# Setting focus to a PanoramaItem

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, panorama-control

Is there a way to set focus to a PanoramaItem in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7?

I've tried:

```
piResults.Focus();
```

Where piResults is the name of a PanoramaItem.
I've also tried to give focus to one of the controls in the PanoramaItem, but that didn't work either.

If this isn't clear, I'm trying to do the following:
If you press a button on one PanoramaItem, you go to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting the index of the PanoramaItem programatically, like -

```
piResults.DefaultItem = piResults.Items[_panorama_item_index_];
```

This technique is useful during Tombstoning. Here is the XAML for the Panorama control that I tried -

```
<!--Panorama item one-->
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
    <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
    <Button x:Name="FirstButton" Content="Go to second item"
            Click="FirstButton_Click"/>

</controls:PanoramaItem>

<!--Panorama item two-->
<!--Use 'Orientation="Horizontal"' to enable a panel that lays out horizontally-->
<controls:PanoramaItem Header="second item">
    <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
    <Button x:Name="SecondButton" Content="Go to first item"
            Click="SecondButton_Click"/>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

The events handlers are -

```
private void SecondButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  piResults.DefaultItem = piResults.Items[0];
}

private void FirstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  piResults.DefaultItem = piResults.Items[1];
}
```

Hope this helps.
indyfromoz

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, this doesn't really go 'smooth', like wiping. Is there a way to emulate the wipe?

Comment: You could use a StoryBoard triggered through the event handlers