# Interface to have transition when button is pressed

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, panorama-control

i used the solution from [Setting focus to a PanoramaItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953200/setting-focus-to-a-panoramaitem) and i managed to get the result - when a button is click, it jumps to a panorama item/page. However the transition is just a disappear/appear, rather than the "sliding effect".

My question is to how am I able to have the transition with the button being pressed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550) includes some transitions you can use.

Read more (including examples) at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api

**Update**
Those (in the youtube link) look like the transitions created by [Kevin Marshall](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/05/12/windows-phone-7-prototype-002-animated-page-transitions-writeable-bitmaps/) and are also part of [WP7Contrib](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/).

Comment: i still cant attain the sliding effect as shown in this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlVEmr3fQHE . i can only do basic transformation like rotate page and all, but no sliding effect from the storyboarding :/